# Symfony2: AvalancheImagineBundle and relative urls

Tags: image-processing, symfony

I'm using symfony v2.0.7 and AvalancheImagineBundle in a project. I configured all files like https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/blob/master/README.md
But image caching not works and directory for cache has not been created. Also images source are showing dev controler at the begining in src:

```
<img src="/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/uploads/images/logo.jpg">
```

I guess it should be without dev controller:

```
<img src="/media/cache/my_thumb/uploads/images/logo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

the folder is created in your

```
web/media
```

of your project

of course the path changes, depending on the fact if you call it in your dev Environment

http://www.myproject.com/app_dev.php

or the prod Environment

http://www.myproject.com/app_dev.php

Comment: yes, the folder should be created in web/media and image source must be the relative path to thumb <img src="/media/cache/my_thumb/..... Then why it include front controller in relative path? <img src="/media/cache/my_thumb...

Comment: Should there be a difference between the two links here?  Surely http://www.myproject.com/app_dev.php and http://www.myproject.com/app.php ?